# Why does $A^2=I$ imply $nullity(A)=0$?

Tags: matrices

> $A$ is a square matrix, why does $A^2=I$ imply $nullity(A)=0$?

This is the key step in the solution, which I can't get it. Please help

Comment: Thanks for this post. With little modification I just generated a nice problem for my lin algebra students...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose that $Ax = 0$ for some $x$. Then also $A^2 x = 0$, but $A^2 x = I x = x$, so $x = 0$.

Comment: As simple and short as that. +1

Comment: The proof writes itself! +1

Comment: Nice proof, but after all, the problem was also pretty simple.

Answer (score 7):

If you know that invertible matrices have nullity $\{0\}$, then you could just observe that $A$ is invertible.

If you don't know this, then fuglede's excellent elemenary answer suffices.

Comment: Excellent observation. It is invertible because there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=BA=I$. In fact, $B=A$.